# failed to process http post,get,put and delete request from cc3200 launchpad to local server or http server

Tags: c, iot, texas-instruments

//I am using

## define GET_REQUEST_URI  "GET /ms/v_updated.php?id=9,9,9& qty=9,9,9/HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:127.0.0.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n"

for v_updated.php file on my localserver  using my cc3200 launchpad

//and i wanted to know that is this the correct syntax am i using for GET request in cc3200

```
    ![on console i got following outpt]
    [1] STA connected to AP:
    [2]IP Acquired :
    [3]Connection to server created successfully 
    
    HTTP Get Begin:
    Failed to send HTTP GET request
    HTTP Post Get failed
    HTTP gET End:
```

and i also want to know about the json parser being used..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.   Your question needs to be more specific and related to specific points of your code.  Shorten down the code and edit the question to make it clear what your question is.

Comment: i have edited some what ,and  my problem is that i wanted to send send http requests to local server or any http server to fetch html or php pages as per required to process bt i also not aware the json parser being used here

Comment: You should [read this](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your local server is declining requests from CC3200. Try Configuring the local Server. 
If you are using XAMPP, Go to `Config` > `httpd.conf`, open it.
Search `AllowOverride`. You will find the following settings (or Similar ),

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride None
Options None 
Order allow,deny
Allow from None
</Directory>
```

Change `None` to `All`.
It Should look like

```
`<Directory />
 AllowOverride All
 Options All 
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from All
 </Directory>`
```

Comment: Check for HTTP Status codes as well. They tell u a lot about your problems